# Elasticsearch indexing Postgres int4range range

Tags: postgresql, filter, elasticsearch, range

I have a range field named `salary` of type `int4range` for my Postgres database. I intend to index this field to Elasticsearch. May I know what is the recommended way to do this? From what I know there is no range type in Elasticsearch, only integer.

So, do I need to parse int4range's begin and end boundary individually and index them as `salary_begin` and `salary_end` and while searching use the range filter, or is there a better approach?

```
Postgres ==> int4range ==> salary (only 1 field in PSQL)

Elasticsearch ==> integer ==> [salary_begin, salary_end] (2 index fields in ES)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to parse anything. Just use `lower()` and `upper()`:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html

Comment: Yea, tks for the parse method. Actually I am more concerned with how to integrate with Elasticsearch for int4range.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ElasticSearch, so I wouldn't be the right person for that one. That said, though, I'd be delightfully surprised if Lucene or ElasticSearch offered anything remotely equivalent to Postgres' range types in terms of functionality. I'd expect either to index ranges as two distinct int fields, much like you'd have done in Postgres prior to 9.2, resulting in mostly useless btree indexes instead of range-friendly gist indexes.